# Combine Arrays in php without for loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have two arrays 
First is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image] => Copy1vs.jpg
            [title] => V.S Achuthanandhan
            [groupId] => 1
            [masterId] => 1
            [id] => 1
            [itemId] => 1
            [status] => 1

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [image] => Copy1pinarayi.jpg
            [title] => Pinarayi Vijayan
            [groupId] => 1
            [masterId] => 2
            [id] => 2
            [itemId] => 2
            [status] => 1

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [image] => Copy1chandy.jpg
            [title] => Oommen Chandy
            [groupId] => 1
            [masterId] => 3
            [id] => 3
            [itemId] => 3
            [status] => 1

        )
)
```

And Second is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image] => Copy1antony.jpg
            [title] => A. K. Antony
            [groupId] => 1
            [masterId] => 4
            [id] => 4
            [itemId] => 4
            [status] => 1

        )

)
```

How can i combine these two arrays as a single array
like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image] => Copy1vs.jpg
            [title] => V.S Achuthanandhan
            [groupId] => 1
            [masterId] => 1
            [id] => 1
            [itemId] => 1
            [status] => 1

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [image] => Copy1pinarayi.jpg
            [title] => Pinarayi Vijayan
            [groupId] => 1
            [masterId] => 2
            [id] => 2
            [itemId] => 2
            [status] => 1

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [image] => Copy1chandy.jpg
            [title] => Oommen Chandy
            [groupId] => 1
            [masterId] => 3
            [id] => 3
            [itemId] => 3
            [status] => 1

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [image] => Copy1antony.jpg
            [title] => A. K. Antony
            [groupId] => 1
            [masterId] => 4
            [id] => 4
            [itemId] => 4
            [status] => 1

        )
)
```

i tried array_merge method but not working as per my requirement is it possible without using a for loop..?
these arrays gets from databse as

```
$itemListArray = array();
foreach($subcat as $sc){
                $itemList = DB::table('votemasteritems')
                        ->leftjoin('votemaster','votemaster.id','=','votemasteritems.masterId')
                        ->leftjoin('items','items.id','=','votemasteritems.itemId')
                        ->leftjoin('category','category.id','=','items.categoryId')
                        ->select('items.image','votemaster.title','votemaster.groupId','votemaster.id as masterId','votemasteritems.*')
                        ->where('votemaster.groupId',1)
                        ->where('category.Id',$sc->id)
                        ->get();

                array_merge($itemListArray, $itemList); 

            }
```

Comment: How about a good ol' fashioned array_merge() ? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: I edited my post. array merge method is not working. Both the array have same name .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_merge` doesn’t *modify* the arrays you pass to it. It only returns a new array containing all of the values, so in your example you’d have to replace the original array like:

```
$itemListArray = array_merge($itemListArray, $itemList);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, PHP has the `array_merge()` function: http://php.net/array_merge

Use it like `$combinedArray = array_merge($array1, $array2);`.

Comment: i already try that but array merge is not working.i just edited the question.please see

Answer (score 0):

#### Try `array_merge()` function

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

In your case, it should be:

$itemListArray = array_merge($itemListArray, $itemList);

Comment: i have both arrays having same name

Comment: @Vishal In your case, shouldn't it be:
$itemListArray = array_merge($itemListArray, $itemList);

Answer (score 0):

check this one

```
foreach($subcat as $sc){
            $itemList = DB::table('votemasteritems')
                    ->leftjoin('votemaster','votemaster.id','=','votemasteritems.masterId')
                    ->leftjoin('items','items.id','=','votemasteritems.itemId')
                    ->leftjoin('category','category.id','=','items.categoryId')
                    ->select('items.image','votemaster.title','votemaster.groupId','votemaster.id as masterId','votemasteritems.*')
                    ->where('votemaster.groupId',1)
                    ->where('category.Id',$sc->id)
                    ->get();

            $itemListArray[]=$itemList; 

        }
```